# PlaceAutocompleteFragment - Identify calling object in onPlaceSelected method

Tags: java, android, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2

I created 2 objects of class PlaceAutocompleteFragment and set OnPlaceSelectedListener on both.

```
placePickup = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_source);
placePickup.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(this);

placeDrop = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_target);
placeDrop.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(this);
```

**Now, I want to find a way to identify which object has invoked onPlaceSelected() method.**

```
@Override
public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
    latLng = place.getLatLng();

    if (invoking object is placePickup){
        do this;
    }
    if (invoking object is placeDrop){
        do this;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can maintain a boolean variable
when user clicks on pickUp make that variable true.

```
boolean isPickUp=false;
```

onCLlick of pickUp where you load PlaceAutoComplete fragment make it true;
and onCLick of drop make it false;

```
if (isPickUp){
    do pickUp related work;
}
else{
    do drop related work here;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Muhib for replying. Actually, PlaceAutoComplete only has one event i.e OnPlaceSelected.... Anyways, I have achieved what I want by calling onPlaceSelected method inline.

Answer (score 0):

Use Inline call like below.

```
placePickup = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_source);
placePickup.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Pick Up");

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {

    }
});

placeDrop = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_target);
placeDrop.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Drop");             
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {

    }
});
```